# Change the connection string for each request logic into the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext vs Keep in Startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, dbcontext

We are Building the Mutitent Database architecture which requires a dynamic connection based on the tenant.

Change the connection string for each request by relocating the connection string logic into the DbContext's OnConfiguring function vs keeping all DbContext connection strings in Startup.

which is the better approach?

In MyDbContext.cs, I added the services I needed to inject into the constructor.

```
private IConfigurationRoot _config;
private HttpContext _httpContext;

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IConfigurationRoot config, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
      : base(options)
{
    _config = config;
    _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Then override OnConfiguring:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connString = BuildConnectionString(); // Your connection string logic here
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is healthier to do it in the OnConfiguring method. But in both options, you may experience problems when you add improvements in the future. My experiences with these problems;

- Parameterizing the constructor can make it difficult to create an object when you need a specific solution.
- When you want to do DbContext pooling, ef core will give the error that both methods are invalid.

In order to avoid such problems, you can use Factory Design Pattern.

```
public class YourDbContextScopedFactory : IDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<YourDbContext> _pooledFactory;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public YourDbContextScopedFactory(IDbContextFactory<YourDbContext> pooledFactory,
                                         IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _pooledFactory = pooledFactory;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var context = _pooledFactory.CreateDbContext();

        var tenant = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.YourExtensionMethodForGetTenant();

        if (tenant != null)
            context.Database.SetConnectionString(tenant.ConnectionString);

        //You can set public properties. These properties will be reset when the scoped instance returns to the pool
        context.SomeProperty = "blabla";

        return context;
    }
}
```

In startup;

```
 services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>((provider, options) =>
 {
     //Your context configuration
 });
  
 services.AddScoped<YourDbContextScopedFactory>();
 services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<YourDbContextScopedFactory>().CreateDbContext());
```

There is no definitive answer to the question so my answer is also my personal recommendation.

Comment: Working Just fine. Nice solution.